# Tableview segue not working?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

Yesterday I was working on a project and I came across this error. Kept me up all night! Still no answer that fixes MY ERROR! So what happens is when i tap my cell its not going to next view controller. I made prototype and everything. So before it was giving be a signal sgbart or something and I fixed it with adding this.

This was in -(void)viewDidLoad

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

The error was coming up here -

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Now all that is fixed. Now whenever i go and click a cell its not working.
It is a RSS reader project. Here is the full code.

```
//
//  AppMain.m
//  fcffv
//
//  Created by Ajay Venkat on 6/09/2014.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 AJTech. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppMain.h"
#import "AppDetail.h"
@interface AppMain () {
    NSXMLParser *parser;
    NSMutableArray *feeds;
    NSMutableDictionary *item;
    NSMutableString *title;
    NSMutableString *link;
    NSString *element;
}
@end
@implementation AppMain
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    feeds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://bountyboulevardss.eq.edu.au/?cat=3&feed=rss2"];
    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
    [parser parse];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return feeds.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
   cell.textLabel.text = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"title"];
    return cell;

}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    element = elementName;

    if ([element isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

        item    = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        title   = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        link    = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    }

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

        [item setObject:title forKey:@"title"];
        [item setObject:link forKey:@"link"];

        [feeds addObject:[item copy]];

    }

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

    if ([element isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        [title appendString:string];
    } else if ([element isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
        [link appendString:string];
    }

}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSString *string = [feeds[indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"link"];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setUrl:string];

    }
}

@end
```

Thank you guys for helping. 
By the way I have done all the re search I could do and all leaves me in failure and even more error so please try help me guys.
Also I am new to Objective-C.

Thank you to people who take the time to help me.
This is a project important to a school.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you implement didSelectRowatIndex method ? And set delegate ?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Cheers S.

Comment: Sorry umm, what do I do once i implement that code?
Do i put that in implementation and the put {}? If so what do i put in it???

Comment: If you set delegates of data source and for table View this method will call automatically after press a cell

Comment: I know I am causing a bit of trouble for you but , I am only12 years old. I am creating app for my school which is really important. Would be great if you copy my code and change it where it is meant to be changed. Please Please help on this . Thank you. Your the best if you do this, I am such a beginner, I need help from a professional like you. Thank you a lot.

Comment: self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
add this and now after you press cell in your tableview didSelectRowAtIndexPath will call automatically

Comment: Thanks I will try. Thanks a lot I will mention you in my about page. For helping, my email is programmer75@rocketmail.com

Comment: Ok I tried what you said, nothing is working. I am going to send you the files above if you can analyse it and see exactly what is causing the problem. The problem is occurring in the file AppMain

Comment: Thank you please comment here if you have downloaded the file. It is an RSS feed so it does not have set cells. The file is AppMain.

Comment: I don't have time now, this toutorial looks good try it http://www.guilmo.com/how-to-create-a-simple-uitableview-with-static-data/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60770/discussion-between-xcoder-and-salsores).